# how to initialize a formset with dynamic number of data entries

Tags: python, django, dynamic, view, formset

Im able to populate my formset with the elements of an array which is **actuals_data** only when i know the number of elements in the array prior to running my code, which is 12 for this code,but how to populate the formset from the array when i dont know the number of elements in the array prior to running my code, which comes in variable **count**.

my view is

```
def show_actuals(request):

Account_Number_in = request.session['account_number']
Year_in = request.session['year']
count = request.session['count']
actuals_data = request.session['actuals_to_show']
months = request.session['months']
show_actuals_formset = formset_factory(FetchActualsBox, extra=0)

formset = show_actuals_formset(initial=[{'Value': actuals_data[0]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[1]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[2]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[3]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[4]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[5]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[6]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[7]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[8]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[9]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[10]},
                    {'Value': actuals_data[11]},
                    ])



return render_to_response('ShowActualsData.html', {'formset' : formset , 'count' : count, 'actuals_data' : actuals_data , 'months' : months , 'Account_Number' : Account_Number_in , 'Year' : Year_in })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate and create list with given number of items.

Sample code:

```
def show_actuals(request):

    Account_Number_in = request.session['account_number']
    Year_in = request.session['year']
    count = request.session['count']
    actuals_data = request.session['actuals_to_show']
    months = request.session['months']
    show_actuals_formset = formset_factory(FetchActualsBox, extra=0)
    initial_list = []
    for data in actuals_data:
       initial_list.append({'value': data})
    formset = show_actuals_formset(initial=initial_list)
```

Comment: Please don't tell people to use a counter to iterate through a list. You should iterate through the list itself: `for i in actual_data...`, and in fact that can be done in a list comprehension.